# What is the relation between z-index and css Position:?

Tags: css, xhtml

What is the relation between `z-index` and css `Position:`?

Is `z-index` only works if `position:absolute` or `relative` or `fixed` defined?

Does it never works with position static?

When `z-index` creates problem in IE? How to use carefully?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`z-index` defines the stacking order of relative, absolute and fixed position elements.  That means that it will only work if your element has one of those position types.

```
.some-element {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}

.another-element {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

In the above, .another-element will stack above .some-element since it has a higher z-index.

The issue with older versions of IE is that z-index is only respected in the same [stacking context](http://www.quirksmode.org/bugreports/archives/2006/01/Explorer_z_index_bug.html).  What this means is that in the following setup, z-index won't necessarily work correctly if the 2 images overlap:

**HTML**

```
<div id="elem1">
    <img src="foo.jpg"/>
</div> 
<div id="elem2">
    <img src="bar.jpg"/>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#elem1 {
    position: relative;
}
#elem1 img {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
#elem2 {
    position: relative;
}
#elem2 img {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

The reason being that both images are in their own stacking context since #elem1 and #elem2 are position: relative.

Comment: Suggestion: Inline the styles so one doesn't need to jump back and forth between the HTML and CSS.

Comment: @pat - so z-index doesn't care about positioning. element with higher z-index will be always on top. Am i right?

Comment: @metal-gear-solid: Yep, z-index isn't affected by the type of position, but it will only work if one of the 3 position types is specified on the element.  And see the bit in my answer about stacking contexts to see where this isn't always true in IE.

Comment: @Pat - Is "stacking level" same thing like layers in photoshop?

Comment: @pat - are IE6 and 7 only browsers which has `z-index` problem?

Comment: @pat- i created one z-index example here http://jsbin.com/uxihu3. with the help of this can you explain the problem of z-index in IE?

Comment: @metal-gear-solid: I'm not 100% positive, but they're the only two I've ever had problems with.  A workaround if you run into the problem is to apply z-index to the elements that have created the stacking contexts (i.e. in my example, you could add z-index to #elem1 and #elem2 to fix the problem).

Answer (score 2):

Note the `Applies to:` section of the [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#z-index):

> ```
> 'z-index'
>    Value:     auto | <integer> | inherit
>    Initial:   auto
>    Applies to:    positioned elements
> ```

—

And you can easily use the index to find the [definition of positioned](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#positioned-element)

Comment: I appreciate the references (+1), but why not also state the answer plainly?

Comment: @Patrick McElhaney - Agree with you. I was also expecting in plain. W3C links content is very long.